# Why the function doesn't work when I click on the respective element?

Tags: javascript

```js
// PART 1 -- CREATING THE TABLE USING ARRAY

let table_elements = [
    ["Krishna", 3, 47.3],
    ["Robert", 2, 47.4],
    ["Jennifer", 4, 82],
    ["Dekisugi", 1, 71],
    ["Muhammad", 5, 68]
];

let getTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

window.onload = () => {
    getTableData();
}

function getTableData(){
    table_elements.forEach((value, index) => {
        let tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for(let x=0; x<table_elements[0].length; x++)
        {
            let td = document.createElement("td");
            td.innerHTML = table_elements[index][x];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        getTable.appendChild(tr);
    });
}

// PART 2 -- SORTING THE VALUES UPON SELECT AN OPTION

function sortByCategory(n){
    n = n.selectedIndex; /* value of n must be 1 in this case */
    // console.log(n);
    let isString = typeof table_elements[0][n-1];
    // console.log(isString);
    var sortingOrder = document.getElementById("sortingOrder").value;
    if(isString == "string")
    {
        if(sortingOrder == "Ascending")
        table_elements.sort();
        else
        table_elements.sort().reverse();
    }
    else
    {
        if(sortingOrder == "Ascending"){
            table_elements.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a[n-1] - b[n-1];
            });
        }
        else{
            table_elements.sort(function (a, b) {
                return b[n - 1] - a[n - 1];
            });
        }
    }

    for(let y=1; y<table_elements.length + 1; y++){
    
        let getTR = getTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[y];
            
        for(let z=0; z<table_elements[0].length; z++){
            let getTD = getTR.getElementsByTagName("td")[z];
            getTD.innerHTML= table_elements[y-1][z];
        }
    }
    function ascending(){
        // sortingOrder = "Ascending";
        sortByCategory();
    }
    function descending(){
        sortByCategory();
    }
}
```

```html
    <select onchange="sortByCategory(this)">
        <option value="--SORT BY CATEGORY--" selected disabled>--SORT BY CATEGORY--</option>
        <option value="Sort by Name">Sort by Name</option>
        <option value="Sort by Roll No.">Sort by Roll No.</option>
        <option value="Sort by Attendance">Sort by Attendance</option>
    </select>
    <select id="sortingOrder">
        <option value="Ascending" onclick="ascending()">Ascending</option>
        <option value="Descending" onclick="descending()">Descending</option>
    </select>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Roll No.</th>
            <th>Attendance</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

In this code everything is okay, but I need to order the table elements as ascending or descending. So, when I select ascending or descending it should sort according to the event. But I need to click on the sort by category options again, then it works. I tried to run the function sortbycategory when I select ascending or descending. But it still not works. Try the code, you will understand what I'm saying. So how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Isn't your `select onchange="sortByCategory(this)"` taking the enire string value ??? instead of function ??

Comment: @SumitYadav I don't have problem with this. When I click ascending or descending the function should run again so that the elements sort as ascending or descending, but it's not happening.

Comment: sortByCategory(n) takes n as parameter which is not supplied when calling it inside descending()

Comment: another big problem is that the functions `ascending` and `descending` do not actually trigger

Comment: take out method outside, sortByCategory method. You have defined this method inside a function hence javascript is not able to recognize these method..

Comment: can any of you give the solution, I'm not getting you.

Comment: Just a note: you can write `window.onload = getTableData;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// PART 1 -- CREATING THE TABLE USING ARRAY

let table_elements = [
  ["Krishna", 3, 47.3],
  ["Robert", 2, 47.4],
  ["Jennifer", 4, 82],
  ["Dekisugi", 1, 71],
  ["Muhammad", 5, 68]
];

let getTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

window.onload = () => {
  getTableData();
}

function getTableData() {
  table_elements.forEach((value, index) => {
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (let x = 0; x < table_elements[0].length; x++) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = table_elements[index][x];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    getTable.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

// PART 2 -- SORTING THE VALUES UPON SELECT AN OPTION
var sortingOrder = 'Ascending'
var sn = 0

function sortByCategory(n = null) {
  let isString = null
  if(n){
     n = n.selectedIndex; /* value of n must be 1 in this case */
     console.log("value of ",n);
     sn = n-1
     isString = typeof table_elements[0][n - 1];
     // console.log(isString);
   }
  if (isString == "string") {
    if (sortingOrder == "Ascending")
       table_elements.sort();
     else
       table_elements.sort().reverse();
   } 
  else {
    if (sortingOrder == "Ascending") {
         if (sn === 0) {
            table_elements.sort(function(a, b) {
             if (a[sn] > b[sn]) {
              return 1
            } else if (b[sn] > a[sn]) {
               return -1
            } else {
              return 0
            }
           });
          }
            else {
             table_elements.sort(function(a, b) {
               return a[sn] - b[sn];
             }); }
          
       } 
   
   else {
         console.log('descending' ,sn)
          if (sn === 0) {
             table_elements.sort(function(a, b) {
             if (a[sn] > b[sn]) {
              return -1
             } else if (b[sn] > a[sn]) {
              return 1
             } else {
              return 0
             }
            });
          }
       else {
             table_elements.sort(function(a, b) {
               return b[sn] - a[sn];
             });
        }
    }

}
for (let y = 1; y < table_elements.length + 1; y++) {

  let getTR = getTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")[y];

  for (let z = 0; z < table_elements[0].length; z++) {
    let getTD = getTR.getElementsByTagName("td")[z];
    getTD.innerHTML = table_elements[y - 1][z];
  }
}

}

function sortTable(order) {
  sortingOrder = order.value
  sortByCategory()
}
```

```html
<select onchange="sortByCategory(this)">
  <option value="--SORT BY CATEGORY--" selected disabled>--SORT BY CATEGORY--</option>
  <option value="Sort by Name">Sort by Name</option>
  <option value="Sort by Roll No.">Sort by Roll No.</option>
  <option value="Sort by Attendance">Sort by Attendance</option>
</select>
<select id="sortingOrder" onchange="sortTable(this)">
  <option value="Ascending">Ascending</option>
  <option value="Descending">Descending</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Roll No.</th>
    <th>Attendance</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's showing error upon selecting ascending or descending

Comment: it's fine, can you explain please how you did it? why you add return 0, 1 or -1 ?